# Call JavaScript function at Jquery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onerror

I've a javascript function `setErrorImages()`, which searches all `img` tags and and gives them an `onerror` function. This works great.

I also have a division `content` with dynamic content by calling de `jquery .load` function like this, which also works:

```
$("#content").load("http://example.com/otherpage.php");
```

But when the new content (otherpage.php) was loaded into the division, the `setErrorImages()` function doesn't work on the `img`'es within the new content.

I can call the `setErrorImages()` function on the otherpage.php, and everything works perfectly, but this way I have to do this on every otherpage, which are a lot.

Is there a way to send a javascript file or function with the `jquery .load`,
or maybe there is a way to re-execute the javascript function right after the `jquery .load`.

Kind regards,
Liontack

---

```
function setErrorImages(){
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        images[i].onerror = function(){ setErrorImage(this); };
    }
}

function setErrorImage(image){
    image.onerror = null;
    image.src = 'http://tanuri.eu/images/error.png';
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your setErrorImages() function?

Comment: Sure, I added it to my question.

Comment: Your `setErrorImage` would be better using `this` instead of `image` and then just use `images[i].onerror = setErrorImage`.

Comment: @Alnitak, the improvements you suggested do work and the code is smaller (I like that). But I don't actually understand why I can use this and use a short for function on the .onerror. Could you provide some links to look into for me?

Comment: Every JS function call has a "context" (aka `this`), so if you call `myobj.func()` the context is `myobj`.  When the browser calls the `onerror` handler it automatically arranges that `this` refers to the element on which the handler is being invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#content").load("http://example.com/otherpage.php", setErrorImages);
```

**.load()** accepts a "complete" parameter:

> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

Comment: Thanks, it works wonderfully. I already looked into the "complete" parameter, but didn't exactly understand its purpose.

Comment: Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suggest using the `this` context instead of a parameter for your error handler:

```
function setErrorImage() {
    this.onerror = null;
    this.src = 'http://tanuri.eu/images/error.png';
}
```

Secondly, change `setErrorImages` to use `this` too:

```
function setErrorImages() {
    var images = this.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0, n = images.length; i < n; ++i) {
        images[i].onerror = setErrorImage;    // parameter is now implict
    }
}
```

Note how there's now no need for a function wrapper for the `onerror` call - the browser automatically sets `this` to be the element of interest.

For simpler code you could also just use jQuery to do this job for you since you already have it loaded:

```
function setErrorImages() {
    $('img', this).error(setErrorImage);
}
```

Thirdly, use the `complete` handler of `.load`, taking advantage of the fact that it sets `this` to be the parent of the part of the DOM that just got replaced.  This avoids setting the `onerror` handler on elements in the page that you already looked at.

```
$('#content').load(url, setErrorImages);
```

The only other change is that on your initial invocation you'll need to pass `document` to `setErrorImages` using `.call`:

```
setErrorImages.call(document);
```